# c time formattings

Tags: c, time, format, structure, time-t

How do I format a time_t structure to something like this year-month-day h:m:s,
I have already tried using ctime:

```
time_t t = time((time_t*) NULL);
char *t_format = ctime(&t);
```

but it doesn't give me the desired results

example :
2011-11-10 10:25:03. What I need is a string containing the result so I can write it to a file. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [strftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) from `time.h` like so:

```
char tc[256];
strftime(tc, 256, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tm);
```

Comment: Also call `struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);` first.

Comment: I got it and btw you can write "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" as "%F %r"

Comment: @onica No, %H:%M:%S is not the same as %r, but %T is.

Answer (score 1):

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strftime.html